# How do i select buttons using php and enter into database?

Tags: php, html

Here is my current code..

```
<form action="js.php" method="post">
<input type="button" id='approve' value="Yes" onclick="a()" class="approve" />
<input type="button" id='reject' value="No" onclick="r()" class="reject"/>
<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="TRUE" /> 
</form>
```

This is my form and the page title is js.php..

I want that if the user clicks on any of the button the name of the button should bge entered into the database into a table called response under the heading response.

How Do i do that?Thanks..

I have done some PHP part...

```
<?php

require_once('connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
    //if on button click

    mysqli_select_db($connect,"check");

    //entering query


}
    ?>
```

here is what Im using to enter the data

```
<?php

require_once('connect.php');


    //if on button click

    mysqli_select_db($connect,"pubd");

    //entering query
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'approve') {
    // user clicked Yes
    $yes = "insert into response (button) values ('approve')";
    $yesr =  mysqli_query($connect,$yes) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
} else if ($_POST['action'] == 'reject') {
        $no = "insert into response (button) values ('reject')";
    $nor =  mysqli_query($connect,$no) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
}



    ?>
<form action="js.php" method="post">
<input type="button" id='approve' name="action" value="Approve" onclick="a()" class="approve" />
<input type="button" id='reject' value="Reject" name="action" onclick="r()" class="reject"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking for an answer how to check which button was clicked, here it is:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" id='approve' value="Yes" name="action" class="approve" />
<input type="submit" id='reject' value="No" name="action" class="reject"/>
```

PHP:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'Yes') {
    // user clicked Yes
} else if ($_POST['action'] == 'No') {
    // user clicked No
}
```

Comment: oh great and how do i enter the result into the database?

Comment: yess...database name...pub...and...table name...response...with one row called button..varchar.

Comment: oh i know how to enter the data, but it is not working..check my edit

Comment: You forgot to change input type to "submit".

Comment: i ams till getting undefined indiex

Comment: Does it happen after you click a button? By the way, strings are case sensitive. 'Approve' != 'approve'.

Comment: could it be because i have two form in js.php which are refering to the action as js.php

Comment: what is the above code? should i replace it with my current one?

Comment: You can check isset($_POST['action']) before doing anything in PHP part.

Comment: well, by doing isset..the errors have gone but the database remains empty.